# Opening MS Access 2007 reports from outside MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way I can open an MS Access 2007 report without opening the actual MS Access DB? I have some reports in my MS Access DB which is located in a sort of server computer. Some people needs access to the reports but I don't want them having the need to open MS Access to view the reports.

Also, I am trying to avoid to develop an app just for this purpose. I'm just trying to find a quick solution for this.

Comment: Just export reports to PDF or RTF and users can view them outside MS Access.

Answer (score 2):

Only Access will open Access reports.

You (users) may use the runtime version, but that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Opening Access reports outside of Access isn't possible without exporting them to PDF, Excel, etc. (as @Parfait mentioned in comments)

A MS Access report, without exporting, is only able to be opened within MS Access.

You're able to export to Excel using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet` with the VBA of MS Access.

Example:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "myExportQry", "C:\users\Me\Documents\Report.xls", True
```

EDIT: edited answer to show the use of the file path within the export line

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tableau on the backend and generate your report data there. (www.tableau.com) they have a free trial so you could try it out and see if its worthwhile for you. Tableau allows you to set up your queries and have set reports based on the data you are collecting in access.

A second possibility would be to split your database and create a front end that only includes those reports.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only data you can simply open excel;
data
you click on the icone at left: from access db

then yo browse to your data base and open the data in the table;

if yo want to avoid any maniplation from others, yo can create a macro with a button to allow any that operation

yo can aloso copy the data on excel and update according to the needs...